# How to replace cpan Perl utility P5NCI with FFI:Platypus

Tags: perl, ffi, cpanm, platypus

Below is perl code which calls P5NCI::load_func to load function load_library having signature as int load_library(int dummy), hence third argument is passed as ii to P5NCI::load_func

```
    my $library_path = P5NCI::find_lib( 'ESNMP.so' );
    $library      = P5NCI::load_lib( $library_path );
    print "\nLibrary loaded";
    print "\nlibrary_path".$library_path;
    my $funcldlib = P5NCI::load_func( $library, 'load_library', 'ii');
```

This was working fine till perl-5.14, but later I used it for perl-5.26.3, but I am getting error as below:

```
Don't understand NCI signature 'ii'
```

I am thinking to use FFI platypus. I have successfully compiled Platypus using below steps:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install FFI::Platypus
```

Wanted to know how can I use FFI::Platypus to achieve same purpose as mentioned in above code with P5NCI

Regards,
Amit Mendhe

Comment: hmm? The documentation is quite clear. What did you try?

Comment: @ikegami Not just documentation I checked Platypus.pm source code.
As in old P5NCI.pm there were find_lib, load_lib,load_func subroutine defined.
But in  Platypus.pm I dont find all this subroutines,

Comment: *"This was working fine till perl-5.14, but later I used it for perl-5.26.3, but I am getting error"* : Yes I tested this on perl 5.34 and am getting the same error. The issue has been reported 10 years ago in [this](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=77325) ticket

Comment: *"ESNMP.so"* Can you provide a link to this library, or its source code? I tried to google it but could not find it

Comment: @HåkonHægland: yes this is broken from perl 5.14 onwards, hence we are using alternate options like FFI:Platypus.
ESNMP.so: this is my internal dynamic library generated from my C source code which I am loading and calling function inside id from perl code.

Comment: *"As in old P5NCI.pm there were find_lib, ... subroutine defined. But in Platypus.pm I dont find all this subroutine"* See https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::CheckLib#find_lib . It should do the same as P5NCI::find_lib()

Comment: @HåkonHægland, what about  P5NCI::load_func or any suggestion for calling c function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243615/discussion-between-amit-m-and-hakon-haegland).

Comment: Re "*But in Platypus.pm I dont find all this subroutines,*", It's all in the SYNOPSYS! The first thing after the module's name and its version. Well, almost. You need to look down to `->lib` to load a library other than libc.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use [`FFI::Platypus`](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus) and [`FFI::CheckLib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::CheckLib) to do the same as you did with `P5NCI`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use FFI::Platypus;
use FFI::CheckLib;

my $libname = 'ESNMP';
my @libs = find_lib(lib => $libname, libpath => './lib');
die "Could not find libary '$libname'\n" if !@libs;
my $libpath = $libs[0];
my $ffi = FFI::Platypus->new();
$ffi->lib( $libpath );
my $function = $ffi->function('load_library', ['int'] => 'int');
my $input_value = 2;
my $return_value = $function->($input_value);
say "Return value: ", $return_value;
```

Note that this assumes that there is a file (the shared library) under the current directory called `lib/libESNMP.so`. This was the path I used for testing this script. I also assume that there is a function called `load_library()` defined in the shared library that takes an integer input argument and returns an integer.

Comment: Great thanks a lot let me try this.

Comment: Hi @ Håkon Hægland, As I checked, if we provide, ESNMP name then for linux it checks for libESNMP.so while my legacy library name is ESNMP.so, is there any way to get exact library name .

Comment: As of now I proceeded with creating symbolic link: libESNMP.so -> ESNMP.so

Comment: @ Håkon Hægland Thanks for the solution this is working perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of

```perl
my $library_path = P5NCI::find_lib( 'ESNMP.so' );
my $library      = P5NCI::load_lib( $library_path );
my $funcldlib    = P5NCI::load_func( $library, 'load_library', 'ii' );

my $j = $funcldlib->( $i );
```

is

```perl
use FFI::Platypus qw( find_lib_or_die );
 
my $ffi = FFI::Platypus->new( api => 1 );
$ffi->lib( find_lib_or_die( lib => 'ESNMP' ) );
$ffi->attach( load_library => [ 'int' ] => 'int' );

my $j = load_library( $i );
```

This is copied almost verbatim from the [module's documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus)'s synopsis. Please make an attempt to answer your own questions in the future.

Note that I find it very suspicious that a function called `load_library` has an `int` parameter. Is its parameter really an `int`? A string seems more likely. But, it was declared as an `int` in the P5NCI versions, so I declared it as an `int` in the FFI::Platypus version.

---

Note that FFI will look for `libESNMP.so`, but you appear to have an unconventionally-named library. You could use the very same function P5NCI used to find it instead of using `find_lib_or_die`.

```perl
use Dynaloader qw( );

my $lib_path = DynaLoader::dl_findfile( 'ESNMP' )
   or die( ... );
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. After adding the changes I am facing new issues. I will create new question for that.